# PHP combine arrays

Tags: php

I have two arrays:

```
aid = [$aid]=>1
amount = [$aid] = $70
```

How can I rewrite these two separate arrays to be one array:

```
payout = [aid] => $aid, [amount] => $70
```

Comment: You should give real arrays as example here. Otherwise it's hard to understand. Where does the `1` end up?

Comment: For starters, your examples aren't valid PHP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are looking for php's array_merge(...)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_merge(). Check this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp

Answer (score 2):

If you want the resulting structure to resemble this:

```
Array
(
    [aid] => 234323
    [amount] => 32454
)
```

Then you can simply use the `+` operator to combine the two arrays:

```
$payout = $aid + $amount;
```

Demo: http://www.ideone.com/ZxP97

Comment: +1 The `+` operator does compare keys, but it is meaningless in that case. I would have used `+` over `array_merge` myself for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($aid); $i++){
    $payout[$i]["aid"] = $aid[$i];
    $payout[$i]["price"] = $price[$i];
}
```